# Swift 4: Prevent SubView of UIView from moving outside it's parent

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

i have a `UIView`, and a half size SubView on it. the user can move the subview around the main view, which's what i want, but the problem is, when the user drags the `UIView` to the corners of the `MainView`, the subview disappears and go underneath it's parent,

`Main UIView` Size: 105x105

`SubView` Size: 35x35

Please take a look at this sample

[image]

I want to lock the subview from moving outside `MainView`, i achieved the dragging by the following code:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch = touches.first!

    self.subview.center = touch.location(in: imageview) // here

    if touch.view == self.imageview  {


    if touch.location(in: view).x >= 245 {

        self.rotateMe.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 1)

    } else {

        self.rotateMe.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -1)
    }

    }


}
```

But I can't lock the subview.

Comment: Could you not put a check that verifies the subviews frame with respect to the superviews frame size?

Comment: @AatishMolasi, what?

Comment: something like 
if (subview.origin.x + subview.size.width) > parentview.width { subview.origin.x = parentview.size.width - subview.size.width
}  
Do the same on the y axis with height

Comment: @AatishMolasi, thank you so much, that only works for the bottom and the right side, not like i wanted

Comment: you can put the conditions similarly for the top and left too
  check origin < 0 for both

Comment: @AatishMolasi, why not to make this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this must work for you requeriments

```
import UIKit

class DraggableView: UIView {

    var localTouchPosition : CGPoint?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        let touch = touches.first
        self.localTouchPosition = touch?.preciseLocation(in: self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        let touch = touches.first
        guard let location = touch?.location(in: self.superview), let localTouchPosition = self.localTouchPosition else{
            return
        }

        let origin = CGPoint(x: location.x - localTouchPosition.x, y: location.y - localTouchPosition.y)
        if(origin.x >= 0 && origin.y >= 0){
            if(origin.x + self.bounds.size.width <= self.superview!.bounds.size.width && origin.y + self.bounds.size.height <= self.superview!.bounds.size.height)
            {
                self.frame.origin = origin
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        self.localTouchPosition = nil
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        self.localTouchPosition = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer, unfortunately your code allows me to only drag a uiview on my screen, whichs not what i want, i want to drag a UIView in a parent view without letting the subview get out of the parent

Comment: You need drag the subView or the parent view? @RawandAhmad

Comment: If you need drag the subView the my answer solves your problem, this work on any parentView, the only requirement is that the DraggableView is inside of any other view @RawandAhmad

Comment: i have two views, i want to drag the secondview which's a subview of the firstview, but without letting the second view jump out of the first one

Comment: What you mean with "your code allows me to only drag a uiview on my screen" you can move the DraggableView on any superView @RawandAhmad can you explain me what is wrong in order to help you?

Answer (score 1):

Making this an answer
Put these conditions for the parentview and it's subview

```
if (subview.origin.y + subview.size.height) > parentview.height { 
  subview.origin.y = parentview.size.height - subview.size.height 
} 
if (subview.origin.x + subview.size.width) > parentview.width { 
  subview.origin.x = parentview.size.width - subview.size.width 
} 
if (subview.origin.x < 0) {
  subview.origin.x = 0
}
if (subview.origin.y < 0) {
  subview.origin.y = 0
}
```